# To read RSSI from WiFi Sensor

Tags: java, wifi, rssi

Please help me how to write a code in Java to read the Received Signal Strength Indicator from the WiFi sensor. 
I tried to do so using socket programming but all my tries weren't get what I want. now I am looking in J2me I may get good answer but I see i may need some advices.
Thank you

Comment: offhand I'd guess that you'd need to do some JNI with C; find out how to do it in C and then work on the JNI part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows? WlanAPI should be able to tell you this information which it receives from the WiFi interface so you want to make sure that the WiFi interface on your computer supports whatever bands you need. You neeed to build your own wrappers around the native APIs though.

Comment: Thanks OneDeveloper but I think I need time to read then will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

there is an opensource project with the name PlaceLab which i used for reading the RSSI and BSSID of Access Point for my thesis.. At that time it was hosted at http://www.placelab.org but seems like it isn't accessible anymore but there a project page at SourceForge, here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/placelab/ from where I think you can get the Java wrapper and Spotter.dll with it's source written in C++ ...

Comment: I couldn't find what you means .... but I found code the needs a time to understand it.

Comment: I am trying to execute this code.                                        public static int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) { if (rssi <= MIN_RSSI) {return 0;} else if (rssi >= MAX_RSSI) { return numLevels - 1; } else { int partitionSize = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI) / (numLevels - 1); return (rssi - MIN_RSSI) / partitionSize; } }                                                                                   but how could I get the function values ...

Comment: what do you mean by function values?