# Get Rssi Value From Windows

Tags: windows, rssi

I would like to measure rssi value of modem.Is there any api to get rssi value for Windows?I used to do that with Wifi.Manager in android.But i couldn't find any api for  Windows

Comment: Are you asking RSSI for your WiFi or some other device?  How this device is connected to your Windows Machine?

Comment: yes for wifi.I want to read rssi value of laptop wi-fi chip.

Answer (score 1):

Using Native code is the best. You will need to use WlanQueryInterface() with  wlan_intf_opcode_rssi opcode which will return RSSI value as LONG data type. From there you can convert it to dbm.

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanQueryInterface(
 __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
 __in        const GUID *pInterfaceGuid,
 __in        WLAN_INTF_OPCODE OpCode,
 __reserved  PVOID pReserved,
 __out       PDWORD pdwDataSize,
 __out       PVOID *ppData,
 __out_opt   PWLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE pWlanOpcodeValueType
);
```

Here using opcode  wlan_intf_opcode_rssi you will get RSSI value:

```
WLAN_INTF_OPCODE  >> wlan_intf_opcode_rssi >> LONG
```

Here is the C++ sample on how to start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want C# Try this:
[How to get SSID and RSSI for Win7 using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331570/how-to-get-ssid-and-rssi-for-win7-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Isn't there any Java api?I am much more familiar Java

Comment: I know J2ME has API to get this value directly however not sure any for desktop.. If you are language dependent, its best to phrase clearly in your question.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142485/to-read-rssi-from-wifi-sensor, it talks about PlaceLab sourceforge page and Soptter.dll with Java Wrapper..

Comment: I couldn't use this Interface.In this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765(v=vs.85).aspx there is a sample but it only shows connected wireless infos.I want to see all enable wirelesses rssi values

Comment: That is very easy. you just need to use WlanEnumInterfaces API to enumerate all the currently enabled wireless on local machine. Here is the sample code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192376/wlan-api-for-getting-signal-strenth really help.It find all networks but after that i should find each result's rssi using WlanQueryInterface.                                            dwResult = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(hClient,
                                             &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid,
                                             0, 
                                             NULL, 
                                             &pBssList);         After that  pBssList-->rssi doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since this question appeared on home page for review- the existing answer is outdated.
There is now a [Managed Wifi API](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=managedwifi) available as a wrapper around the [Windows Native Wifi API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/NativeWiFi/about-the-native-wifi-api).

Signal strength in percentage and RSSI could be obtained as,
Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);

```
Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] redes = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList(); //Get the atribute that you need

foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in redes)
{
    Console.Write("Network SSID {0} RSSI {1}\n ", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid),
 network.rssi);
 }
```

Comment: The first link is no longer valid.