# C++ Wifi Signal Strength

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi

I'm trying to get the strength of the connected wifi signal using c++ on a Windows 7 machine.

I can get a value for the strength of the signal using the command [`WlanGetAvailableNetworkList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749(v=vs.85).aspx) but the value returned is not granular enough for our requirements.  Basically as you move away from the Wifi router the value jumps in increments of 20% (99% -> 80% -> 60% etc).

For the application we are developing we really need a more accurate value.  I know it's possible as I have seen apps in windows displaying accurate dBm values for signal strength...

If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated!

```
dwResult = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(hClient,&pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid,0,NULL,&pBssList);

if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"WlanGetAvailableNetworkList failed with error: %u\n", dwResult);
    dwRetVal = 1;

} else {

    for (j = 0; j < pBssList->dwNumberOfItems; j++) {
        pBssEntry = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK *) & pBssList->Network[j];

        if ((pBssEntry->dwFlags & WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED ) != 0 ){

            if (pBssEntry->wlanSignalQuality == 0)
                iRSSI = -100;
            else if (pBssEntry->wlanSignalQuality == 100)   
                iRSSI = -50;
            else
                iRSSI = -100 + (pBssEntry->wlanSignalQuality/2);    

            wprintf(L"  Signal Quality[%u]:\t %u (RSSI: %i dBm)\n", j, 
                pBssEntry->wlanSignalQuality, iRSSI);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after continuing research online I managed to patch together a way that works for me.  From what I've read - there are many different ways of obtaining the RSSI - but this method, while maybe a little cumbersome, worked well for our needs...

I'm using the command WlanGetNetworkBssList, and then getting the RSSI value directly from the returned  PWLAN_BSS_ENTRY.

I found it is important to call WlanScan each time before querying WlanGetNetworkBssList, otherwise the returned value doesn't change with any sort of regularity.

```
HANDLE hClient;
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfConnInfo = NULL;
PWLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES pConnectInfo = NULL;

PWLAN_BSS_LIST pBssList=NULL;
PWLAN_BSS_ENTRY  pBssEntry=NULL;
WLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE opCode = wlan_opcode_value_type_invalid;

DWORD dwResult = 0;
DWORD dwMaxClient = 2;         
DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;
DWORD connectInfoSize = sizeof(WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES);

int i;

// Initialise the Handle
dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{    
    return 0;
}

// Get the Interface List
dwResult = WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{    
    return 0;
}

//Loop through the List to find the connected Interface
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < (int) pIfList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) 
{
    pIfInfo = (WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO *) & pIfList->InterfaceInfo[i];    
    if (pIfInfo->isState == wlan_interface_state_connected) 
    {
        pIfConnInfo = pIfInfo;
        break;
    }
}

if ( pIfConnInfo == NULL )
    return 0;

// Query the Interface
dwResult = WlanQueryInterface(hClient,&pIfConnInfo->InterfaceGuid,wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection,NULL,&connectInfoSize,(PVOID *) &pConnectInfo,&opCode);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{    
    return 0;
}

// Scan the connected SSID
dwResult = WlanScan(hClient,&pIfConnInfo->InterfaceGuid,&pConnectInfo->wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid,NULL,NULL);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{    
    return 0;
}

// Get the BSS Entry
dwResult = WlanGetNetworkBssList(hClient,&pIfConnInfo->InterfaceGuid,&pConnectInfo->wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid,dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure,TRUE,NULL,&pBssList);

if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{    
    return 0;
}

// Get the RSSI value
pBssEntry=&pBssList->wlanBssEntries[0];
return pBssEntry->lRssi;
```

Answer (score 1):

wlanSignalQuality is an interpolation of the RSSI. Take a look at this answer question for how to get the RSSI directly:

[Get Rssi Value From Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760006/get-rssi-value-from-windows)

Comment: Thanks Cookie - I did look into this a few days ago.  I tried getting the RSSI value this way - but I have no idea of how to convert it to dBm.  The value was completely different each time I ran the program and each time I called WlanQueryInterface the value grew by 32.  5627392, 5627424, 5627456 ect...

Comment: @flinthart There is no universal conversion, it's a relative and unitless metric that depends on device if you actually want to do any conversions.