# RSSI using Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi, rssi

I am trying to get the RSSI using the windows API. So far, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760006/get-rssi-value-from-windows) thread saying to use the wlan_intf_opcode_rssi with the WlanQueryInterface function. I am not too sure what the reply means on that thread and was hoping someone could clarify.

All i have managed to understand from the other thread is this:

```
WlanQueryInterface(hClient,
   &pInfo->InterfaceGuid,
   wlan_intf_opcode_rssi,
   NULL,
   &connectInfoSize,
   (PVOID*)&pConnectInfo,
   &opCode);
```

I am not sure what to do after here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you getting an error code back from `WlanQueryInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong type of argument to `WlanQueryInterface`. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms706765(v=vs.85).aspx) that the return type for `wlan_intf_opcode_rssi` is LONG, so you need to pass a pointer to a LONG variable, like this:

```
LONG rssi = 0;
DWORD dwSizeRssi = sizeof(rssi);
dwResult = WlanQueryInterface(hClient,
    &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid,
    wlan_intf_opcode_rssi,
    NULL,
    &dwSizeRssi,
    (PVOID *)&rssi,
    &opCode);

if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    wprintf(L"RSSI = %u \n", rssi);
}
```

Comment: I know this has been some time, but I have been using your code to get the RSSI. It seems like I get far too high values (underflow?) e.g. 984188178. I tried replacing your `%u` format specifier with `%d` or `%ld`, but the issue remains the same. The return value of `WlanQueryInterface` is still `ERROR_SUCCESS ` though. Do you happen to have any clue? Thanks