# How to get the RSSI and SNR values from TCP sockets

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I am communicating between two laptop machines(both running Ubuntu 12.04 ) using TCP sockets. Is there a way to programmatically extract extract RSSI and SNR values for each incoming packet , as is possible with radio-tap?

Answer (score 1):

RSSI and SNR belong to the lower layers and depend on medium being used. TCP has no information about it.

Secondly these values are for point to point communication. A TCP connection would span over different media and a single RSSI / SNR value does not make sense.

These links might be helpful:

- [WiFi management tool to monitor a mobile device](https://superuser.com/questions/217087/wifi-management-tool-to-monitor-a-mobile-device)
- [To read RSSI from WiFi Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142485/to-read-rssi-from-wifi-sensor)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a way i can access some Layer 2 API and get the RSSI and Noise values? Can i read the values as reported by iwconfig  and assume that it the SSI and Noise value for the incoming packet? Or am i missing something here? Could you help me out?

Comment: I don't know of any such API. What is the medium? Is it Wi-Fi? GPRS/3G/4G Modem? For GPRS/3G/4G modems there are AT commands that can be used to get this information.